# Getting emoji counts in a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, analytics, emoji

```
def emoji_counter(string):
no_of_emojis = 0
for char in string:
    if char in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI_ENGLISH:
        no_of_emojis += 1
return no_of_emojis
```

I have written the above code. It works fine only for some emojis. But for a string like this
"Oh, come on!!‍♂️" ( I am analyzing a whatsapp text )

The output for emoji_counter function is 4

When I copied the string to the one of the cells in my Jupyter Notebook, it shows extra two characters (a red dot and a gender symbol next to it). How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. The reason you are getting wrong count is because, how the emojis are setup. Some of the emoji's are combination of emoji's

In your case ‍♂️ is actually [shown as this in Jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Vb9r.png)"

I have checked other emoji's also. Mostly the one that has a gender associated with it comes out like this.

Let me know if this helps.